# How to use regex while selecting rows from snowflake external stage?

Tags: sql, regex, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created following things:

1. External Stage (pointing to folder in Data Lake Gen2)
2. File Format (Parquet)

And I want to do a select from a stage but I want to read only those files that have .*part.* in there filename. Using copy into command I am able to mention this in pattern but I do not want to copy data in a table. I only want to do a select for .*part.* files. Currently I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    $1:Country::String as Country,
    $1:FeatureStr::String as FeatureStr,
    $1:Machineid::String as Machineid,
    $1:ProductId::number as ProductId
FROM @DB.RAW_SCHEMA.FEATURE_STAGE/ClientDetails/2020.03.ClientDetails/ (file_format => DB.RAW_SCHEMA.PARQUET_FORMAT);
```

But it also looks for files which do not have '**part**' in them and so it fails. So then I tried the pattern functionality:

```
SELECT 
    $1:Country::String as Country,
    $1:FeatureStr::String as FeatureStr,
    $1:Machineid::String as Machineid,
    $1:ProductId::number as ProductId
FROM @DB.RAW_SCHEMA.FEATURE_STAGE/ClientDetails/2020.03.ClientDetails/ (file_format => DB.RAW_SCHEMA.PARQUET_FORMAT)
pattern => '.*part.*';
```

But it gives me syntax error. Any guidance will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are after is:

```
select * 
from @STAGE_NAME/PATH
(FILE_FORMAT => PARQUET_FORMAT, PATTERN => '.*[.]part[.].*' )
```

Square brackets in the regex are there to also match the dots in *.part.*. The regex you used will work to just match all the files with the word *part*

Comment: thanks, Yeah this is what i was looking for. Can you please also look into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823080/how-to-run-snowflake-side-effect-functions-like-systemgenerate-scim-access-toke